# Skype for business chat and call the user from my web application

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

We are developing a web application which is hosted in IIS with windows authentication enabled. (The authentication is done through Active directory)

The application is designed as a collaborative tool where all the organization users can interact with each others.

We are in a need to integrate SkypeforBusiness feature in our web application where as the user can see his collegue's presence, call or chat with him directly from the application.(The Skype for Business service is online but web application that need to consume is going to be in on-premise)

I am going through some articles from MSDN regarding SDKs and UCWA but could not get the solution for my needs.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/SkypeWebSDK)?

Comment: Hi yes, i have analysed these links already [SkypeOnPrem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/developforskypeforbusiness), [SkypeOnline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline) but i could not get the sample working code for my need, i am trying to integrate SDK for online since our skypeforbusiness is in online, but wondering do we need to really register the application and go through oauth.. it looks like bit complecated

Comment: Our application is hosted in IIS with simple windows auth enabled, but to integrate, i dont want to register in Azure and go through oAuth process ,  Please suggest me the right path.